# Should We use Handler for long delay Android

Tags: android, handler, threadpool

I am using Handler in service and using it's method `handler.sendMessageDelayed(message,time)`.
This method is working fine for short period of time but not working(sometimes) for long time like 3,5,10 minutes.Should I use handler for such long delays?

Comment: Where did you place looper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not. You should look into AlarmManager to execute some task in the future.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: I know this.but I don't know what is the issue with handler?

Comment: Man, where is your Looper? It depends only on it.

Comment: Handler is tied to your applications main thread (or some background thread if you created your handler there), and it can lose the access to some of its resources or even vanish along with it when onDestroy() is called. AlarmManager is a system service and it does not really depend on the state of your application.

Comment: The only thing handler need is Looper! If your Looper is in your main thread, than, maybe it was destroyed by gc.

Comment: But I am using Handler in service that is running for all the time...So I think handler should not vanish.